# Android: Split Activity with a movable border

Tags: android, layout, drag

I have the following structure of a layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    ...
  </ScrollView>
  <ScrollView>
    ...
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The screen is divided into two parts: upper and lower. Is there a way to make **a border** between ScrollViews which the user will be able to drag up and down **to resize both Views** at the same time?

So basically what I want to achieve is this:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, the [Android Split Pane Layout](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout) is exactly what you're looking for. Very simple and easy to implement.